Issue with creating zod object type with generic property
I am attempting to create a zod schema for a recursive type:
type FieldSpec<Fields extends string> = {
    typ: "simple";
    field: Fields;
} | {
  // typ: "div";
  typ: "div" | "/";
  numerator: FieldSpec<Fields>;
  divisor: FieldSpec<Fields>;
} | {
  // typ: "mul";
  typ: "mul" | "*";
  fields: [FieldSpec<Fields>, FieldSpec<Fields>, ...FieldSpec<Fields>[]];
} | {
  // typ: "add";
  typ: "add" | "+";
  fields: [FieldSpec<Fields>, FieldSpec<Fields>, ...FieldSpec<Fields>[]];
};

I am using a generic function to create the schema, but unfortunately it is not returning the correct type for the "simple" FieldSpec.
The z.infer type of the mathematical operations is correct (e.g. the following for the "add" spec)
type TA = {
    typ: "add" | "+";
    fields: [FieldSpec<Fields>, FieldSpec<Fields>, ...FieldSpec<Fields>[]];
}

The z.infer type for the "simple" type is reported as the following:
type TS = { [k in keyof z.objectUtil.addQuestionMarks<z.baseObjectOutputType<{
    typ: z.ZodLiteral<"simple">;
    field: z.ZodType<Fields, z.ZodTypeDef, Fields>;
}>, any>]: z.objectUtil.addQuestionMarks<...>[k]; }

Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this issue, as it is preventing the returned schema from type checking:
Types of property 'field' are incompatible.
            Type 'addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<{ typ: ZodLiteral<"simple">; field: ZodType<Fields, ZodTypeDef, Fields>; }>, any>["field"] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Fields'.
              'Fields' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<{ typ: ZodLiteral<"simple">; field: ZodType<Fields, ZodTypeDef, Fields>; }>, any>["field"] | undefined'.

Typescript playground link
EDIT:
I have attempted to parse the "simple" field as an enum, and that also failed.
If I specify the type of simple as z.ZodType<{ type: "simple"; field: Fields }> then I get the following error at the definition of simple:
Type 'ZodObject<{ type: ZodLiteral<"simple">; field: ZodType<Fields, ZodTypeDef, Fields>; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { [k in keyof addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<{ type: ZodLiteral<...>; field: ZodType<...>; }>, any>]: addQuestionMarks<...>[k]; }, { [k in keyof baseObjectInputType<...>]: baseObjectInputType<...>[k]; }>' is not assignable to type 'ZodType<{ type: "simple"; field: Fields; }, ZodTypeDef, { type: "simple"; field: Fields; }>'.
  The types of '_type.field' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<{ type: ZodLiteral<"simple">; field: ZodType<Fields, ZodTypeDef, Fields>; }>, any>["field"] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Fields'.
      'Fields' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<{ type: ZodLiteral<"simple">; field: ZodType<Fields, ZodTypeDef, Fields>; }>, any>["field"] | undefined'.ts(2322)

